# Coloring a line plot based on a third factor in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having a hard time with a coloring scheme in `ggplot`. If someone could help me out or send me to another question that would be fantastic.

I have data that look along the lines of

```
day=rep(1:10, 5)
year=rep(1992:1996, each=10)
state=rep(c("A","B"), each=25)
set.seed(4)
y=runif(50, 5.0, 7.5)
df=data.frame(year,day,state,y)
> head(df)
  year day state        y
1 1992   1     A 6.464501
2 1992   2     A 5.022364
3 1992   3     A 5.734349
4 1992   4     A 5.693437
5 1992   5     A 7.033936
6 1992   6     A 5.651069
```

I want to create a plot similar to the below. Using the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
p = ggplot(df, aes(day, y))
p = p + geom_line(aes(colour = factor(year)))
print(p)
```

[image: Line Plot]

I want the coloring to be based off of the `state` variable. I would like the years that are in state 'A' to be one color and the years in state 'B' to be another.

Thank you

Comment: Does this not work: `colour = factor(state)` ? Instead of `colour = factor(year)`.

Comment: So you want separate colors for each combination of state and year? If so, `colour=interaction(state, factor(year))`.

Comment: Your graph might be easier to understand if you use a different aesthetic for `state`, such as linetype or linewidth.

Comment: @zx8754 No, It will only have two lines, one for 'A' and one for 'B'... I still want one line for each year

Comment: @eipi10 Kinda I tried that, It makes each combination of the 2 a different color]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want it separated by years but colored by state the key is to use the group= argument:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=day, y=y, group=year, colour=state)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Thank you Forrest! That is exactly what I was looking for!